# Where are object files of c programs stored?

Tags: c

After a c source code is compiled, an object file is created. I can only see the .exe file so where can I find the object file? I am using cygwin on windows so I am using gcc to compile programs.

Comment: Sounds like your build system doesn't save the intermediate object files. Since you say .exe I assume you're on Windows, what compiler are you using?

Comment: It depends on your toolchain. What is your toolchain ?

Comment: They seem to be deleted right after linkage. There should be an option for keeping them, but it depends on your compiler.

Comment: Why are you claiming with certainty that "an object file is created"? Who said that?

Comment: I am using gcc on cygwin. I guess I just assumed since I saw some text referring to a .o extension for object files.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Many compilers support the `-c` option to compile only and produce object files.

If you use a `make`-based build, object files may be treated as *intermediate* and automatically removed. You may declare them in the `.PRECIOUS:` target to avoid this.

If your program consists of only a single C source file, you could use

```
gcc -c file.c       # Creates file.o, but no file.exe
gcc -o prog file.o  # Creates prog.exe by linking file.o with appropriate libs
```

Answer (score 2):

As a language-lawyer answer, because the standard doesn't specify an "object file" must be created when a source is being compiled:([Quotation from N1570, 6th footnote](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#note6), emphasis mine)

> 6) Implementations shall behave as if these separate phases occur,
>   even though many are typically folded together in practice. Source
>   files, translation units, and **translated translation units need not
>   necessarily be stored as files**, nor need there be any one-to-one
>   correspondence between these entities and any external representation.
>   The description is conceptual only, and does not specify any
>   particular implementation.

However, note that on most main-stream implementations, "object files" are generated and deleted. If you want to keep them, add the `-c` flag (works on both GCC and clang).

Answer (score 0):

It is implementation specific. Some (weird) implementations of C are interpreters, or (e.g. tinycc) may compile in memory (so don't produce any files). Others (e.g. my [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler, when not asked to...) don't keep object files (so when you `gcc -Wall foo.c bar.c -o prog.exe` the `foo.obj` & `bar.obj` are temporary so are not kept; but YMMV).

Comment: Probably because you mentioned interpreters and the question is about compilation. Some may read to fast.